# Making post request to a specific object within an array in db.json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I am making a signup form in a react app. The form has five inputs; name, username, email, password, and favTeam. I want this info, when submitted to be sent to my backend (right now just a db.json file). Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react' 
import Header from './Header' 

const SignupPage = ({goToProfilePage}) => { 
    const [name, setName] = useState('')  
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')  
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('') 
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')  
    const [favTeam, setFavTeam] = useState('') 

    const handleNameChange = e => {
        setName(e.target.value) 
        console.log(name)
    }  

    const handleUsrChange = e => {
        setUsername(e.target.value)  
    }  

    const handleEmailChange = e => {
        setEmail(e.target.value) 
    }  

    const handlePswdChange = e => {
        setPassword(e.target.value) 
    } 

    const handleFavTeamChange = e => {
        setFavTeam(e.target.value) 
    }   

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {  
        e.preventDefault() 
        console.log('submitted') 
        try{ 
            const postRequest = async () => {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users', {
                    method: 'POST', 
                    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}, 
                    body: JSON.stringify({"user-info": {
                        name: name.value, 
                        username: username.value, 
                        email: email.value, 
                        password: password.value, 
                        fav_team: favTeam.value 
                    }
                    })
                })
                if (response.ok){
                    const respToJson = await response.json() 
                    console.log(respToJson) 
                }
            } 
            postRequest() 
            // goToProfilePage() 
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error)  
        }
    }

    return(
        <>  
            <Header/> 
            <form id='signup-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <input id='name' name='name' placeholder='Name' type='text' value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
                <input id='username' name='username' placeholder='Username' type='text' value={username} onChange={handleUsrChange} />
                <input id='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' type='email' value={email} onChange={handleEmailChange} />
                <input id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password' value={password} onChange={handlePswdChange} />
                <input id='fav_team' name='favTeam' placeholder='Favorite Team' type='text' value={favTeam} onChange={handleFavTeamChange} />  
                <button>Create account</button>
            </form>  
        </>
    )
}  

export default SignupPage `
```

... and here is mydb.json file. When submitted the form should create a new "user" object, and this info should specifically fill out a "user-info" object:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "user-info": 
                {   
                    "id": 0, 
                    "name": "fake person", 
                    "username": "fake_person", 
                    "email": "fakeemail@email.com", 
                    "password": "fakepassword", 
                    "fav_team": "Baseball Team" 
                }, 

            "user-games": [
                {
                    "date": null, 
                    "result": "Win", 
                    "score": "1-0", 
                    "opponent": "Fake Team", 
                    "location": "Fake Stadium", 
                    "starting_pitcher": "Fake Pitcher", 
                    "note": ""
                } 
            ], 

            "user-stats": 
                { 
                    "games": 0, 
                    "wins": 0, 
                    "losses": 0, 
                    "percentage": 0
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

I made a standard post request as seen in the code above, but it gives me an internal server error (500 error) when the form is submitted.